# mySQL query giving inaccurate results

Tags: mysql

This is my current query:

```
select baseball , const.cnt/count(*) as my_percent 
from full_db3 inner join
 (select count(*) as cnt from full_db3 where gender = 'f') const
group by baseball
order by my_percent desc limit 10;
```

This yields inaccurate results. The possible values for `baseball` are TRUE and FALSE, which appear in my result's `baseball` column. However, the values for `my_percent` are all off. Not even close.

If I run this query (different `GROUP BY`), I get the correct value in `my_percent` for FALSE, but TRUE isn't in the result.

```
select baseball , const.cnt/count(*) as my_percent 
from full_db3 inner join
 (select count(*) as cnt from full_db3 where gender = 'f') const
group by const.cnt
order by my_percent desc limit 10;
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simpler:

```
select baseball , 
      (sum(case when gender = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) * 100 as pct
FROM full_db3
group by baseball;
```

This query gives percentage of females that are players / non players;

```
select gender, 
   (sum(baseball) / count(baseball)) * 100 as players, 
   (1 - (sum(baseball) / count(baseball))) * 100 as non_players
    from full_db3
    where gender = 'f'
    ;
```

And the last one, that has the true / false in the rows, as finally determined as the requirement:

```
 select baseball, 
    (count(*) / 
       (select count(gender) from full_db3 where gender = 'f')) * 100 as pct
 from full_db3 
 where gender = 'f'
 group by baseball;
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15866/6

Comment: Thanks. This runs without error, but the results are wrong. I'm getting back TRUE and FALSE in my `baseball` column, which is right, but the values in `pct` are all wrong. They should add up to 100, but this sums to 130.7. Neither of the values is correct on its own.

Comment: If I remove the `group by baseball` I get the correct value for FALSE only. TRUE isn't shown in the query result.

Comment: You need to explain what value you want then. The answer you are getting is the percentage of all (baseball = true) that are female, and the percentage of all (baseball = false) that are female. Do you simply want what percentage of females do or dont have baseball = true?

Comment: I should have 2 rows return...one for TRUE and one for FALSE. However, only one row returns (FALSE) with the correct value in the `pct` column. I need the second row that should be TRUE in the `baseball` column and a correct value in the `pct` column.

Comment: does it have to be true false in the rows?

Comment: Those are the values in the database, so yes, they return that and have to be that.

Comment: sorry i mean is it okay if they are in the columns, as per my second query above?

Comment: The new query give me one row with 3 columns. gender is "f", players="0" and non-players  is ="100". This clearly isn't correct unfortunately.

Comment: Bottom line that I'm trying to get to: Given gender of "female", what percentage like baseball (i.e., TRUE) and what percentage don't (i.e., FALSE). This needs to be repeatable for other factors such as age instead of gender and/or football instead of baseball.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74304/discussion-between-pala-and-jonmrich).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to show percentages of people who play baseball.

Don't you want

```
SELECT baseball, gender, (100.0 * COUNT(*) / const.cnt) AS my_percent
  FROM full_db3
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM full_db3) CONST
 GROUP BY baseball, gender
```

You might also want.

```
SELECT baseball, gender, (100.0 * COUNT(*) / const.cnt) AS my_percent
  FROM full_db3
  JOIN (
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, gender
       FROM full_db3
      GROUP BY gender
       ) CONST ON full_db3.gender = CONST.gender
 GROUP BY baseball, gender
```

If you want to know what percentage of 'm' and 'f' genders separately have the baseball attribute.

The `100.0 *` turns your fraction into a percentage

Your `LIMIT 10` makes no sense in this case because your aggregate query doesn't contain ten different categories.

Comment: Your query gives me "Unknown column 'const.cnt' in 'field list'" and the second gives me "Column 'gender' in field list is ambiguous". I'm trying to specify the (for example) gender (e.g., female) and get back what percentage of women play baseball (true v false).